# Android Add 7.5 hours to a specific date

Tags: java, android

In my Android application, I have 3 spinners for Hour/Minute/ and PM or AM. I'd like to add 7.5 hours in that to get the needed time for the user to sleep. This android application of mine is a calculator of a user's sleep. For example, I'd like to wake up at 7:00 AM. BY 11:15 PM you should now be sleeping. Please give me some directions on how to do this. I'm in dire need of help. Thanks. Appreciate your help.

like this:

```
  /**
   * Get sleeping times corresponding to a local time
   * 
   * @param wakingTime
   *            time to wake up !
   * @return list of times one should go to bed to
   */

  public static Set<Date> getSleepingTimes(Date wakingTime) {

    Set<Date> result = new TreeSet<Date>();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime( wakingTime );
    calendar.add( Calendar.MINUTE, -14 );
    calendar.add( Calendar.MINUTE, -( 2 * 90 ) );
    for ( int i = 3; i <= 6; i++ ) {
      calendar.add( Calendar.MINUTE, -90 );
      result.add( calendar.getTime() );
    }
    return result;

  } // end of getSleepingTimes method
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please show the relevant code where you try to add the time.

Comment: I've added it. Please if you know something that would help. I just found this in a site but don't know how to implement this.

Comment: That's confusing! :)  What are you trying to achieve exactly?  What is the purpose of the for loop?  Why are you returning a set of dates, and why are you using TreeSet?  You seem to be subtracting 194 minutes then subtracting a further 90 minutes, 3 times each of which subtractions is a result.  This doesn't tie in with subtracting 7.5 hours.  And does the user supply 7.5 hours or are you hard coding it?

Comment: As I've said, it is just what I have found on the Internet, I'd like to try to add my own 7.5 hours to the set waking time of the user. Sorry if you're confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Date getSleepingTimes(Date wakingTime) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime( wakingTime );
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR,-7);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE,-30);

    return calendar.getTime();

}
```

but better not to hard code the 7.5 hours.

```
public static Date getSleepingTimes(Date wakingTime, int hoursToSleep, int minutesToSleep) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime( wakingTime );
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR,-hoursToSleep);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE,-minutesToSleep);

    return calendar.getTime();

}
```

use like this:

```
   getSleepingTime(wakingTime, 7, 30);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, what I'm troubled with is how do I implement this one in Android's spinners?

Comment: By the way, I'm developing in Gingerbread. If I'm not mistaken, Calendar is not implemented yet in 2.3.3? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Calendar has been there for ever!  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html  What do you mean "implement this one in Android's spinners"?  Set the sleep time in the spinners?  Or set the waking time with the spinners?  Or select the 7.5 hours with the spinners?

Comment: I mean the set the waking time in spinners. then I want the sleeping time to display in textview. I know how to display it in textview but the former I know not.

Comment: Do you really want spinners, and not TimePickers? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html

Comment: If I do it in TimePickers, how would I apply the above code?Please assist me.

Comment: I'm wondering if I get the input of the user in timepicker, since hour and minute are integers how are they going to be a date?

Comment: When I tried hour - 7, I got an error. But when I tried hour + 7, it's just not giving my desired result

Comment: Then please start a new question and post your stack trace from logcat.  I don't know what you're doing wrong.  I use this kind of code all of the time and it works.  cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -7);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18067/discussion-between-betty-barnes-and-simon)

Answer (score 0):

You would be using the [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) component. There are the methods

- getCurrentHour
- getCurrentMinute

and

- setCurrentHour
- setCurrentMinute

which you could use to add the additional time.

```
final TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.a_time_picker);
int hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
int minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour + 7);
timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute + 30);
```

You would have to solve the AM/PM problem yourself.

For the future: Please provide the Android SDK level your are developing for.

Comment: Can you give me some piece of code to work on? Or if not, then can you just point me to a good tutorial? THanks mate.

Comment: I added a small example to my original post.

Comment: TimePicker would be the way to go: You can set it to AM/PM mode with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView(java.lang.Boolean)